# Month equivalence and unit restriction in forHumans function

Tags: php, php-carbon

I'm encountering two peculiar behaviors with a library, and my objective is to convert seconds into a readable format displaying `days, hours, minutes, and seconds`.

When attempting to convert `2698447 seconds` into a human-readable format using the Carbon library, I obtain the following result:

```
<?php

use Carbon\CarbonInterval;
use Carbon\Carbon;

echo CarbonInterval::seconds(2698447)->cascade()->forHumans();
```

[image]

However, when using an online converter, the output is different (https://www.tools4noobs.com/online_tools/seconds_to_hh_mm_ss/):

[image: Online Converter Result]

In my code, I also experimented with CarbonInterval, and when converting 28 days and 30 days separately, the output seems to imply that 28 days is equivalent to a month:

```
use Carbon\CarbonInterval;
use Carbon\Carbon;

echo CarbonInterval::seconds(28*24*3600)->cascade()->forHumans(); // Outputs: 28 days
echo "\n";
echo CarbonInterval::seconds(30*24*3600)->cascade()->forHumans(); // Outputs: 30 days
echo "\n";
```

[image: CarbonInterval Results]

Considering these results, I am puzzled about the interpretation of days as a month. How can I configure the conversion to consider a month as 30 or 31 days, and furthermore, is it possible to restrict the output to days as the maximum unit (days hours minutes seconds)?

Comment: There is more information in [the documentation](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-interval), search for: _"1 month = 4 weeks"_, which is 28 days, underneath it tells you how to change it.

Comment: But how to convert to days hours minutes seconds ?

Comment: If I look at the example, it turns `'3w 18d 53h 159m'` into `7 weeks 4 days 7 hours 39 minutes` by omitting the month factor from `CarbonInterval::setCascadeFactors()`. My guess is that if you omit the week factor as well, it will use days as the biggest unit. Have you tried that? Note that I've never used Carbon, I've got my own routines for this, but I can read the documentation. That's why I provide this suggestion as a comment and not as an answer.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I tried using `CarbonInterval::setCascadeFactors([
    'minute' => [60, 'seconds'],
    'hour' => [60, 'minutes'],
    'day' => [24, 'hours']
]);` but I still have week as format :/

Comment: Well, that's a pity. Let's see what other people know about this..... Anyone?!

Comment: I saw [this issue](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/issues/1546), which suggests a solution. Out of caution I installed Carbon, all 1046 files or 2.75 MB of it, but I couldn't make this solution work. Perhaps you have more luck?

Comment: Perhaps now is the time to tell you that it is quite easy to do this conversion without Carbon? Afterall, we know there are 86,400 seconds in a day. So dividing 2,698,447 by that gives you the number of days. You can [get the remainder with the modulo operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php), Rinse and repeat: There are 3600 seconds in an hour. And do on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can skip the units you don't want in the `forHumans()` options:

```
echo CarbonInterval::seconds(2698447)->cascade()->forHumans([
    'skip' => ['week', 'month', 'year'],
]);
```